# How to make FloatingActionButton take you to specific tab in Tab Layout

Tags: java, android, floating-action-button

I have a `FloatingActionButton` in my android `navigation drawer` with `tablayout` which displays the following message :

```
fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            homeFragment();
            SnackBarMessage("Go To Inbox.");
        }
    });
```

using snackbar

```
public void SnackBarMessage(String message){
        Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayout, message, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction("Action", null).show();
    }
```

let's say I have 3 tabs e.g (tab 0 ,tab 1 , tab 2)

how can I make the Floating action button take me to tab 2 once I click on it

This is the fragment containing the tabs

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    ArrayList<String> tabName;

    public HomeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        mViewPager = (ViewPager)view.findViewById(R.id.container);
        tabName=new ArrayList<String>();

        int [] tabIcons = {
                R.drawable.ic_home,
                R.drawable.ic_move_to_inbox,
                R.drawable.ic_notifications,
                R.drawable.ic_swap_horiz,
                R.drawable.ic_people,
    };
    String[] strings = { "Main Page Goes Here", "Messages Go Here", "Notifications Go Here", "Trade Page Goes Here", "People Online Page Goes Here"};

        for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
            tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(tabIcons[i]));
            tabName.add((strings[i]));
        }
        tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE);
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(),tabLayout.getTabCount(),tabName);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
        mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
                getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null).commit();
            }
            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            }
        });
        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        // Note that we are passing childFragmentManager, not FragmentManager
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(),tabLayout.getTabCount(),tabName);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

Comment: you can implement it in the activity where tab layout is declared.

Comment: yes i know, but how is this possible, can you please give me a reference or documentation?

Comment: first, you have to post your code.

Comment: new code updated

Answer (score 0):

To be able to do this from another Fragment you will need to send a something in a Bundle, such as the position of the page, then do something like this:

```
HomeFragment fragment = new HomeFragment();

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt(YOUR_PAGE, youPage);
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);

    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment).addToBackStack("Name").commit();
```

Then in your HomeFragment:

```
Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
if (bundle != null) { viewPager.setCurrentItem(bundle.getInt(YOUR_PAGE) }
```

Comment: what does YOUR_PAGE reference to here?

Comment: The position of the your target page in the ViewPager

Comment: im doing it from another activity not fragment

Comment: in fab onclick listener is there anyway i can refrence the tabs from the constructor homeFragment();